# remove Protected section from Documentation?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have been using doxygen to generate html document for my project. And my generated documents contain a files tab. How could I remove protected attribute and protected member function fields from it?

Protected Member Functions
Protected Attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not wish something to be extracted it should not have a documentation block.  In your release provide a header file that has only the methods you wish to be exposed, create a separate header file for your own use.  You may also use the \internal flag if you want internal documentation for your benefit, however this would also require that the prototype for hidden methods be exposed.

In general:

```
/** \internal My personal documentation
* Public documentation..................
*/
```

*doxyfile*
    EXTRACT_ALL= 0,
    HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS= 1,
    INTERNAL_DOCS = 1 or 0

Comment: yeah i found something relevant..we have some thing called \cond and \endcond methods in doxygen that allows us to hide part of our code from being exposed to documentation